# Kafka connect transform ValueToKey not recognising value type

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, avro

In my Cassandra connector configuration, I'm trying to create a composite primary key for Cassandra but I'm facing some issues.
The producer is serialising the message using Avro.

**Connector configuration**

```json
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.cassandra.CassandraSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "topics": "events",
  "cassandra.contact.points": "cassandra",
  "cassandra.local.datacenter": "dc1",
  "cassandra.port": "9042",
  "cassandra.keyspace": "mykeyspace",
  "cassandra.table": "events_by_trackable",
  "cassandra.security": "NONE",
  "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema_registry:8081",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema_registry:8081",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "confluent.topic.replication.factor": 1,
  "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafka_broker:9092",
  "transforms": "ValueToKey",
  "transforms.ValueToKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
  "transforms.ValueToKey.fields":  "trackable_type,trackable_id,created_at"
}
```

When I read the topic with the console consumer it returns the deserialised message correctly but without the key present.

**kafka-avro-console-consumer**

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka_broker:9092 --property schema.registry.url=http://schema_registry:8081 --topic events --from-beginning --max-messages 10 --property print.key=true
null    {"id":"f3c183a2-3c0c-11ee-be54-da85ce8f1b40","actor_id":"123","trackable_owner_id":"12312","event_type":"View","trackable_type":"Product","trackable_id":"1234","created_at":1692173682188390,"metadata":{"user-agent":"Firefox"}}
```

When I check the task trace I can see that it's throwing an error and it's unable to process the message.
It's considering the field to be a Blob instead of a string `[BLOB <-> java.lang.String]`

**Error**

```bash
curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors/cassandra-sink/status" | jq -r ".tasks[0].trace"
...
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Exception thrown while processing one of the fields
    at io.confluent.connect.cassandra.BoundStatementConverter.convertStruct(BoundStatementConverter.java:406)
    at io.confluent.connect.cassandra.BoundStatementConverter.convert(BoundStatementConverter.java:293)
    at io.confluent.connect.cassandra.CassandraSinkTask.put(CassandraSinkTask.java:120)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:590)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [BLOB <-> java.lang.String]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:609)
...
```

**Schema configuration**

```bash
curl http://localhost:8081/subjects/events/versions/latest
{"subject":"events","version":1,"id":8,"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"events\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"actor_id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"trackable_owner_id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"event_type\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"trackable_type\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"trackable_id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"created_at\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"metadata\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"map\",\"values\":\"string\"}}]}"}
```

**Cassandra table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mykeyspace.events_by_trackable (
    id                  UUID,
    actor_id            TEXT,
    trackable_owner_id  TEXT,
    event_type          TEXT,
    trackable_type      TEXT,
    trackable_id        TEXT,
    created_at          TIMESTAMP,
    metadata            MAP<TEXT, TEXT>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((trackable_type, trackable_id), created_at)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC);
```

Can you see anything wrong with my setup?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it's doing any harm but you have `key.converter.schema.registry.url` configured. I think your key is just a string and not using a schema right?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, I tried to remove it but didn't make a difference

Comment: Your key isn't Avro. That's what the other comment is referring to. You've not explicitly defined AvroConverter as the key converter (yes, it's necessary) therefore, ByteArrayConverter could be used instead causing data to be a BLOB... so try **adding** key converter and keep the registry url, and see

Comment: Also, the `events` subject means nothing to the converter. You should check both `events-key` and `events-value` subjects

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I've added to my config
`"key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter", "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema_registry:8081"`
and checked the `events-value` and `events-key`, they are identical to `events` apart from the `subject` and `id` fields.
After restarting the connector and task I still see the same error.

Comment: Also by inspecting the registry logs I only see requests to the events-value
`"GET /schemas/ids/9?fetchMaxId=false&subject=events-value HTTP/1.1" 200 643 "-" "Java/11.0.18" 2 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)`
`"POST /subjects/events-value?normalize=false&deleted=true HTTP/1.1" 200 687 "-" "Java/11.0.18" 3 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)`